# Reading from EEPROM problem

Tags: eeprom

I write a structure into EEPRM as follows

```
typedef struct
{
   fract32 AmpF; // amplitude fundamental
   fract32 AmpH; // amplitude harmonic 
   UINT32 b;
   UINT16 d;
   UINT16 crc;

}CoilBoardAmp_T;

// mechanic angles and salt water angles of coil stored in coil-eeprom
typedef struct
{
    ChannelData_T     channel[NUM_CHANNELS];
    CoilBoard_T       coilboard;
    CoilBoardAmp_T    coil_h;
    CoilBoardAmp_T    coil_d;
//  UINT32    gCoilSerialNumber;
//  UINT32    gInversSerialNumber;
} Coil_Eeprom_Data_T;
```

I set that data by a software, which writes to that structure.

The problem is when reading that structure at the first time without writing to it, I read false data.

I need to detect that point. How would I know If the data that is read is false, or how would I know that I read the data without the software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add checksum or crc in Coil_Eeprom_Data_T structure. And verify it after reading the data from EEPROM.